# std::bad_alloc "bad allocation" while trying to load a neural network model from the Darknet framework

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019, darknet

I'm trying to use OpenCV's DNN module with C++ in Visual Studio 2019 for the first time and I get this:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8DD52CD29 in ConsoleApplication1.exe:
> Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location
> 0x000000BE8334F150."

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet("yolov4-tiny.cfg", "yolov4-tiny.weights");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::bad_alloc means you don't have enough memory.

Comment: Are you building for 32-bit or 64-bit native?